# How can I get parameters to automatically appear within brackets?

Tags: php, wordpress, notepad++

I am fairly new to PHP and its various resources, so apologies if my question/references has not been wording correctly.

Whilst following various YouTube tutorials on PHP Coding for WordPress, I have noticed that many coders are able to automatically generate available Parameters within their strings/arrays etc.  I use Notepad++ and as far as I can see, this is the chosen programme within many of these YouTube Tutorials.  Is there an extension, within Notepad++, for this or do they use a completely different programme?

Comment: Use PHPStorm, its the best for now :)

Comment: Please take a look at this article, as it will assist you in getting the most from this site.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper Answer is that you are looking for auto completion and linting and there are millions of tools for the job.

If anything I would suggest Sublime, Atom or Visual Studio Code. All are free.

However the likes of PHPStorm can give help you out if you are very new to the language with its completion.

It's not free but you can play with it for 30 days and student offers are good.

Notepad++ is an option too but, its limited.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations.  I am currently using Notepad++ but it does not provide me with the 'auto populate' feature (unless there is some kind of extension that I am unaware of).  For now, I will stick with Notepad++ as to complete my WordPress Website Theme and then I will look into your recommendations and experiment.  Once again, thanks for your direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sublime Text which is used for PHP

Comment: @nerdlyist oh..im sorry..im new to SO

Comment: NP just don't want to see you get downvoted and lose rep so close to being able to comment